# How to Display Different Profiles to Customers Using WhatsApp Business API Based on Conditions

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am looking for a way to have my business number communicate with a person but show as different profiles to the customer depending on certain sets of conditions using the WhatsApp Business API. Can anyone provide guidance on how to set this up and manage multiple profiles based on specific conditions using the WhatsApp Business API?

Currently I cannot find any hint on how to do this in the API docs. There seem to be some third party solutions for this (like Trengo ?) which I haven't tried since I cannot use any 3rd party here.

**Update:**

As far as I have found out, it can't be done.